# Reset Row_Number() value when Dense_Rank() value increases

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

I would like to restart the numbering of a Row_Number() column in a SELECT Statement when the Dense_Rank() values increases. I tried to do it with cursor but I faced an issue with rounding of my data. Is there any other way to do it without using of cursor?

```
DECLARE @RowNum as INT;
DECLARE @DenseRank as INT;
DECLARE @DenseRankPrevious as INT;
DECLARE @RD_ROI1_minus_RD_ROI3 as NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @RD_ROI2_minus_RD_ROI3 as NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Cursor as CURSOR;

SET @RowNum = 0;
SET @Cursor = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [RD_RF_ID]) AS DenseRank, [RD_ROI1_minus_RD_ROI3]
    FROM [dbo].[vw_Raw_Data] WHERE [dbo].[vw_Raw_Data].RD_GUID_ID = 433

CREATE TABLE #TempTable(
 RowNum int,
 DenseRank int,
 ROI1_New NVARCHAR(MAX))

OPEN @Cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM @Cursor INTO @DenseRank, @RD_ROI1_minus_RD_ROI3;
SET  @DenseRankPrevious = @DenseRank;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    IF @DenseRankPrevious = @DenseRank
    SET @RowNum = @RowNum + 1;
    ELSE
    BEGIN
    SET @RowNum = 0;
    SET @RowNum = @RowNum + 1;
    SET @DenseRankPrevious = @DenseRank;
    END

    INSERT INTO #TempTable 
    SELECT @RowNum, @DenseRank, @RD_ROI1_minus_RD_ROI3 ;
    FETCH NEXT FROM @Cursor INTO @DenseRank, @RD_ROI1_minus_RD_ROI3;
END

CLOSE @Cursor;
DEALLOCATE @Cursor;

    SELECT * FROM #TempTable 
    DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

The above code gives the following result

```
- 1   1   178.409
- 2   1   173.23
- 3   1   164.867
- 4   1   165.52
- 5   1   153.351
- 6   1   160.773
- 7   1   157.694
```

instead of the following that is the expected.

```
- 1  1  178,409039893888
- 2 1   173,230282624222
- 3 1   164,86654423018
- 4 1   165,52035506581
- 5 1   153,351290684624
- 6 1   160,773492500765
- 7 1   157,694316906438
```

Any idea why this rounding occurs? Thanks in advance!

Comment: i am confused. What is your question ? Is it on row_number or rounding ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you use a cursor for this?

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DenseRank ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as rn,
       rd.*
FROM (SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY rd.RD_RF_ID) AS DenseRank, 
             RD_ROI1_minus_RD_ROI3
      FROM dbo.vw_Raw_Data rd
      WHERE rd.RD_GUID_ID = 433
     ) rd;
```

Comment: The above answer is exactly what I was looking for. The statement works fine, it does not round the data.